# Read dynamically created Entry value inside ListView in Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm totally beginner working with Xamarin using VS2019.
I have a Listview with items created dynamically.
Here the XAML code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding plates}" x:Name="menuView" 
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Large" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Label Text="Qyt:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            <Entry Placeholder="nCant" Text="0" x:Name="txtCant" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               WidthRequest="40" VerticalTextAlignment="End" BackgroundColor="#f2f0f0" ></Entry>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Price}" FontAttributes="Bold"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Large" />
                        </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Button Text="ORDER" FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="LightCyan" WidthRequest="200" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="on_btOrder" x:Name="btCant" />                 
    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And here the code to populate the ListView:

```
        public List<Item> menuFull;
        public List<Item> plates { get; set; }
        clientDB = new httpClient();
        url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?format=json";

        var result = await client.Get<List<Item>>(url);
        foreach (Item prod in result)
        {
            menuFull.Add(prod);
        }

        List<Item> products = new List<Item>();

        if (menuFull.Count == 0)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "DB ERROR", "OK");
            return;
        }

        plates = new List<Item>();
        foreach (Item row in menuFull)
        {
            if (row.Price.Length <= 2)
                row.Price += ".00";
            else
                row.Price += "0";
            plates .Add(new Item
            {
                Name = row.Name,
                Price = row.Price,
            });
        }
        BindingContext = this;
```

Now when user click btOrder button, I need to collect all btCant values.
At the end I need to find a way to know only one Entry value.
Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: you need to use data binding to bind the Entry value to a property of your model.  Then you add the values of your model up to get the total.

Comment: Thank Jason, I'm a complete beginner and I will try to checkout, but can you help me with some basic example to follow please. Really thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the `Entry` to a property on your `Item` model.  Let's assume it's called `Count`

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Count}" ... />
```

then to sum all of the `Count` values in `places`, you can use LINQ

```
var total = plates.Sum(p => p.Count);
```

Comment: Jason, Thanks!
Let me clear what I need.
Each row of the ListView represent a product: Id, Name and Price.
The user will input the quantity of products that need to purchase on the Entry (x:name=txtCant) and when, at the end, the user clicks on "on_btOrder" button I will collect product id and quantity. I know is poor old programming style,  but as a beginner I don't see another way..
Thanks gain for your help !

Comment: you need to add a Qty property to your model, then when your user clicks order you will have all the data your need in `plates`.  Alternately, you could create a new VM that contains `Item` and a `Qty` property.

Comment: Thanks!
Check the answer to see what I did.
The second option option for the VM (ViewModel?)  any ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:
1. Edit the "Item" Model

```
public class Item
{
    #region Private Variables

    public int id;
    public string price;
    public string name;
    public int deleted;
    public int Qyt;
}
```

Now Modify the entry on the XMAL to:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Qyt}" x:Name="txtCantidad" Grid.Row="1" 
                               Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="40" VerticalTextAlignment="End" />
```

Now when I click on button "Order"

```
var total = plates.Sum(p => p.Count);
```

The var "total" show the number of items of the "plates" list

Comment: Hi , if have solved this , remember to mark answer when you have time. :-)